# Small problem with Facebook Autopost module / Facebook App

Tags: rules, social-network

I have installed the Facebook Autopost module after setting up my Facebook App. When I add a new content, my rule should post it to facebook, however I get the following message:

Facebook SDK threw an error: OAuthException (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Do you know what I have or haven't done correctly and how I could resolve this? I think it's something to do with permissions or something in my Facebook App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by setting appropriate permissions for each role under /admin/config/services/fbpermissions